# Qt 5.6, Windows 7 - OpenGL Error 1286 ("Unsupported framebuffer format"), 1280 in qopenglframebufferobject

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am a relative newcomer to OpenGL, which cripples me a bit in tackling the following error.

Here is a minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

#include <GL/GLU.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class OGLErrorTest : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    OGLErrorTest(QWidget *p = nullptr) : QOpenGLWidget(p) 
    {
        QSurfaceFormat sformat;
        sformat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
        sformat.setMajorVersion(2);
        sformat.setMinorVersion(1);
        sformat.setDepthBufferSize(0);
        sformat.setAlphaBufferSize(0);
        sformat.setRedBufferSize(8);
        sformat.setGreenBufferSize(8);
        sformat.setBlueBufferSize(8);
        sformat.setStencilBufferSize(0);
        sformat.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
        sformat.setStereo(false);

        setFormat(sformat);
    }

    ~OGLErrorTest() {}

protected:

    void initializeGL() 
    {
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        GLenum err = glewInit();

        if (err != GLEW_OK) {
            cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }

        const char *glv = (const char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION);
        glv = glv ? glv : "(unable to get OpenGL version)";
        cout << glv << endl;
    }

    void resizeGL(int w, int h) {}

    void paintGL() 
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0, 100, 0, 100);

        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2d(0, 0);
        glVertex2d(100, 100);
        glEnd();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    const char *qt_version = qVersion();
    qt_version = qt_version ? qt_version : "(unable to get qt version)";
    cout << qt_version << endl;

    OGLErrorTest w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The console output of the above program is:

```
5.6.0
2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2104
[opengl\qopenglframebufferobject.cpp line 538] OpenGL Error: 1286
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Unsupported framebuffer format.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Unsupported framebuffer format.
[opengl\qopenglframebufferobject.cpp line 730] OpenGL Error: 1280
```

My Qt version is 5.6.0, and OpenGL version is 2.1.0 (which is fairly ancient I understand). I compile the program on Windows 7 through Visual Studio 2015. If you are running the program, you have to link with the console subsystem and compile it in the debug mode for the errors to be visible.

The image gets displayed correctly. Not issues with that.

However, my question: how can I get rid of the two OpenGL errors (1286, 1280) please? Does it look like a Qt problem, or does it look like it can be gotten rid of by (say) properly configuring the OpenGL context? I think Qt is trying to make use of some features that my hardware doesn't support. If that's the case, my question is, how can I tell Qt to not expect these features to be available?

I tried looking at the source code (qopenglframebufferobject.cpp), but couldn't figure out anything that can be done to fix the error.

Comment: Looks like a problem within Qt's own source file (qopenglframebufferobject.cpp).

Comment: It's indeed a problem inside Qt. You could try stepping through that code and try to figure out why it's trying to build a FBO with "wrong" settings. Most likely, your system doesn't support FBOs with stencil but without depth attachments. Try playing with those in the format selection (e.g. try ask for a "ordinary" 24 bit depth / 8 bit stencil). Also, there's no such thing as profiles in GL 2.1.

Comment: @peppe Tried the depth/stencil changes and some other permutations - the error is still there unfortunately. I will need to educate myself a bit more on OpenGL it looks like!

Comment: Maybe add a breakpoint where that warning is emitted and try to understand what's going wrong. You could consider submitting a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa) with the stack trace and the locals used in that function.

Comment: Btw, it seems that you're using OpenGL with the obsolete fixed function pipeline. Don't waste your time on that but learn shaders instead. Also, you don't need to use GLEW with Qt (Qt has QOpenGLFunctions). There are multiple ways to use OpenGL with Qt, but I would start with this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html

Comment: @juzzlin Thanks for the tip! I know that I need to up my OpenGL game a bit in order to tackle this and several other related problems.

Comment: @peppe The problem apparently was with the graphics driver. I hadn't updated the graphics driver in a long time (5+ years). Since I was getting more errors (memory leaks, crashes on shader syntax errors) with the GLSL version of the program, I recently tried updating the driver to a newer version and sure enough, the problems disappeared!